# query for backup a database at another location in file system

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE <myDataBaseName> TO DISK = 'C:\PathtoBackup\FileName.bak'
```

this query is worked for a database which is created in the gui of SQLServer express edition

I have attached my database which is physically at D drive(D:\testing.mdf) to SQLServer using GUI in SQlServer Mgmt Studio.After attaching, SSMS displays the database name as "D:\testing.mdf" in Object explorer rather than testing.
`SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName`.

This query results the same that "D:\testing.mdf"

The above mentioned BACKUP query is not worked for later

```
 BACKUP DATABASE testing TO DISK = 'C:\PathtoBackup\testing.bak'
```

the following error has been shown

```
Msg 911, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'testing'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally
```

I have tried like this

```
BACKUP DATABASE D:\testing.mdf TO DISK = 'C:\PathtoBackup\testing.bak'
```

the following error has been shown

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'D'.
```

What should I do to backup that file which is at different location in filesystem

Comment: Does that path `C:\PathtoBackup` physically exist on your SQL Server when you run your BACKUP command?? Also: that error message would indicate that the "TESTING" database is not really part of SQL Server - has not been attached / restored properly into that SQL Server instance. Can you see the TESTING database in your Mgmt Studio, and can you query it??

Comment: Yes,C:\PathtoBackup exists.And I attached the database "testing" to SQLserver using GUI in SQlServer Mgmt Studio.After attaching SSMS displays the database name as "D:\testing.mdf" in Object explorer rather than testing.`SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName`.This query results the same that "D:\testing.mdf"

Comment: If the database is called d:\testing.mdf then wrap it in [brackets]. If it is called Testing then use the name of the database rather than the name of the file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you  @[u07ch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31508/u07ch)

I got it.Finally I got the desired result by your tip.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [D:\testing.mdf] TO disk = 'C:\PathToBackup\BackupFileName.bak'
```

The backup file has created successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Path can be any location on your system so following query is working fine to take backup of a database:
`backup database empdb to disk = 'c:/empdb.bak'`